# How to make many to many relationship table efficient for SELECT queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

A user can have many interests. 
An interest can be interested to many users.
My database looks like that:

```
Users table:
      id - primary key,
      name,
      email,

Interests table:
      id - primary key,
      title

Users_To_Interests table:
      id - primary key,
      user_id(id from users table)
      interest_id(id from interests table)
```

How can I improve **Users_To_Interests** table to be able to pick all users who have the same interest efficiently? **user_id** and **interest_id** columns don't have indexes or keys. If I need to add them, please show me how can I make that.

**Edition 1**: For example,

```
user1 has interests : interest1, interest2, interest3;
user2 has interests : interest3, interest4;
user3 has interests : interest3, interest5;
user4 has interests : interest4;

If I want to get all users who have interest1, I should receive user1;
If I want to get all users who have interest2, I should receive user1;
If I want to get all users who have interest3, I should receive user1, user2, user3;
```

Comment: You want an index on `(interest_id, user_id)` and on `(user_id, interest_id)` for the full range of queries you are likely to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the same interests?  Are you looking for exact matches, partial overlaps, or something else?

Comment: You can improve the users_to_interests table by dropping the id field and making the other two fields the primary key.  Among other things, that should index them automatically.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have added an example of what I want to reach

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't have an experience in database architecture. Could you please give me more extended answer with examples or give me a link where can I find this info?

Comment: @DanBracuk Could you please give me an example of how I can make two primary keys in one table?

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: As to two primary keys: The primary key is a unique key on non-nullable columns. You can create additional such indexes: `create unique index idx1 on users_to_interests(interest_id, user_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query which would find all users having interests 1 and 2.  It should be clear how to generalize this to any number of interets.  The subquery aggregates over users and finds those users who have the interests we want.  We then join this back to the `Users` table to get the full information for each user.

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM Users t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ui.user_id
    FROM Users_To_Interests ui
    INNER JOIN Interests i
        ON ui.interest_id = i.id
    WHERE i.title IN ('interest2', 'interest3')
    GROUP BY ui.user_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. Does it use indexes? Should I add indexes to interest_id and user_id fields before? I don't know, if I need somehow mention indexes when I make a query or SQL will use them by default? Actually, I don't understand this concept of indexes. I understood, that when I use indexes SQL will use something similar to binary search for select queries. But, I didn't understand that should I change a SQL query to use indexes, or the query will stay the same.

Comment: The existence of indices in your schema does not depend on any particular query.  Off the top of my head, adding an index on `Interests.title` and `Users_To_Interests.user_id` might help.  But I don't think an index would change the overall logic to my approach.

Answer (score 1):

The query to get users for interest #3 is very simple (use `IN` or `EXISTS`). With an index on `users_to_interests(interest_id, user_id)` this should be very fast.

```
select *
from users
where id in (select user_id from users_to_interests where interest_id = 3);
```

Comment: But what about multiple interests?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Either two `IN` clauses or better changing above subquery to an aggregating query with `HAVING`. However, in the request the suggested queries are all on one interest only, so maybe queries on multiple interests are not even needed here.